# WP7 - Textbox cursor position error

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7

I've got a text box (which I've made changes to by editing the template). I added a `Scrollviewer` to the `border` of the content element so that I have a horizontal scroll ability, just like the address bar text box in IE.

Now that I've added the `ScrollViewer`, when I select the text inside the text box the cursor is positioned incorrectly. A better way to illustrate this is below:

[image]

My XAML is:

```
<ScrollViewer Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}" Width="Auto" BorderThickness="3" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
   <Border BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="Transparent" Height="48" Width="Auto">
    <ContentControl x:Name="ContentElement" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxInnerMargin}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" Style="{StaticResource ContentControlStyle1}"/>
  </Border>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Basically that's it! all I added was that `ScrollViewer` and the error occurs. What can I do to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you *expect* to happen when you select the text? Where do you want the cursor to be? Is there an actual error happening or is the behavior just not what you expect? You'll need to be a little more specific.

Comment: No real error happening just that the selection cursor is positioned incorrectly. Basically I want it so that the selection is inside the Textbox, just like any other textbox when you type text. e.g.: http://puu.sh/6jH1y.png

Comment: Hmm. Still not sure I understand. Are you talking about when you **tap** on the text in the text box, it highlights incorrectly?

Comment: It highlights the text correctly but usually when a user highlights the text in a textbox their given a mini selection cursor which helps them select what they want to highlight in specific (http://puu.sh/6jH1y.png) << in there you get 2 little circles which you use to select what you want to highlight. 

But for me, it highlights correctly but the selection cursor ( 2 little circles) is positioned waayy over the textbox like the picture I've provided on the post.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the ScrollViewer a fixed height

Comment: My best guess would be that it's a bug then. Without the ScrollViewer, is it not possible to move horizontally within the TextBox? Just curious what you need the ScrollViewer for.

Comment: Have you tried simply adding a ScrollViewer around the TextBox in question?

Comment: yea I have tried adding it around. Basically what I try to do is make a Horizontal scrollable textbox just like the adressbar in Internet Explorer, the user can scroll horizontally to view the adress. Adding the scrollviewer to the textbox might be my next thing but I've tried it but it doesn't look as good as adding it inside the textbox.